# PHP Form: Want to have a drop down selection with two values that post to different fields in the form

Tags: php, forms, field, explode

Example, I want the drop down value to be 1278|Toy Name
I would like to then separate via the | and spost the id "1278" in an id field 
and "Toy 2" in a toy field.

I am actually using FormTools (formtools.org) for all of my forms and this is one thing I just can not get my head around.

A little background: This is for a client and needs to be this way. they need the ID submitted as well as the Toy Name into separate Db tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to fill two input fields from the value `1278|Toy Name` then it's a JavaScript thing (check `onChange` event). if you want to just parse the string after submission try it with `explode()` function of PHP

Answer (score 0):

You could split the submitted value based on the `|` and use the retrieved values to insert into the database.

```
$toyInput = $_POST["toyInput"];
$toySplit = explode("|", $toyInput);
$toyID = $toySplit[0];
$toyName = $toySplit[1];

// Now insert $toyID and $toyName into your DB in separate fields.
```

Be aware that this has no validation, a user could easily put fake ID's, names, or a value with no "|" and cause your script to error out.  Be sure to add extra checks for these cases!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `list` that assign values to a list of variables.

```
$toyInput = $_POST["toyInput"];
list($toyID, $toyName) = explode("|", $toyInput);
```